# Matrix catenation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I have this code in Mathematica:

```
nxBin = Table[{-5 sX + (i - 0.5)*step, nBin[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[nBin]}]
```

and I did this in MATLAB:

```
a=zeros(length(nBin),1);
nxBin=zeros(length(nBin),1);
for i=1:length(nBin)
    anew=a*step*(i-0.5) -5*sX;
    b=zeros(length(nBin(i)),1);
nxBin(i,:)=[anew , b]
end
```

but MATLAB says

> ??? Error using ==> horzcat
>   CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.
>
> Error in ==> begin at 52
>   nxBin(i,:)=[anew , b]

Can anyone tell me why I get this error? Also, can I do this with fewer lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to catenate the n-by-1 array nBin with steps (probably x-values for a histogram). Thus, you can simply create the "x-vector" and combine them.

```
nxBin = [ -5*sX + ((1:length(nBin))' - 0.5) * nStep, nBin(:)]
```

Here's the same step-by-step

```
%# make a vector with values from 1 to nBin
x = 1:length(nBin);
%# transpose, since it's 1-by-n and we want n-by-1
x = x'; %'#
%# apply the modification to x
x = -5*sX + (x-0.5)*nStep;
%# catenate with nBin (the colon operator guarantees it's n-by-1
nxBin = [x, nBin(:)];
```

**EDIT**

In case you want to plot this, you can do

```
plot(nxBin(:,1),nxBin(:,2),'.')
```

or, if I guess right and it's a histogram

```
bar(nxBin(:,1),nxBin(:,2))
```

Comment: Jonas,thanks for one more time.Your examples are very helpful for me.I wanted to ask 2 things though : 1) I can't understand how the iteration works on to the second column (nBin(:)).(i understand the first column). 2) Is there any book or somewhere to learn to manipulate like this the matrices?(i study as much as i can from mathworks ,but it more like a reference and it isn't very helpful for me.If you can send me a mail with your suggestions i will be gratefull)

Comment: @George: there is no iteration in `nBin(:)`, it just reshapes `nBin` to be a `n-by-1` array. If you know `nBin` is already the right shape, you can omit it, if you know that it is the wrong shape you can transpose it, of course, but if you don't, you use the colon-reshape just to be safe.

Comment: @George: Have you worked through the ["getting started"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/bqr_2pl.html) section including demos and videos?

Comment: I meant how the 1:length(nBin) passes each time the nBin ,thus,our second column.And ,yes , i have read the getting started section but in these situations i need sth more in depth and with examples.Thanks again

Comment: @George: Oops, I noticed that I forgot to put in `1:length(nBin)` into the long explanation! I'm so used to have the `n-` prefix indicate that the variable contains a `number of` that I forgot that it is a vector in your case. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am trying... :-)..Jonas,if i want to plot "ListPlot[nxBin] and "Plot[km*PN[x, mX, sX]*step, {x, -5 sX, 5 sX}] " and try this "fg1=plot(nxBin,'b.')
fg2=plot(km*g*step,[-5*sX,5*sX]) " I am taking in the first plot the right graph but with wrong x-axis (and it gives me a line in x-axis that i don't want.(where g=@ (x) pn(x,mX,sX));How can i do it?

Comment: If it's any consolation: I have a hard time wrapping my head around Mathematica's programming, since it feels so different from C-based languages.

Comment: Ok,it works.This is not a histogram(i have previous histograms).But in the "Plot[km*PN[x, mX, sX]*step, {x, -5 sX, 5 sX}] " i have problem.I have created a function file which includes "function PN = pn(x,m,s)" and i can't figure how to manipulate it..See my previouw comment.

Comment: @George: Oh, I see. You can first define your x as `x=-5*sX:5*sX;`, and then call `plot` with `plot(x,pn(x,mX,sX)*step)`

Comment: @George: Have you had a look at `x` (by double-clicking on it in the workspace browser)? Is it empty? If yes, it's because 5*sX is less than 0.5 and the default step size is 1. In this case, you need to adjust the step size, either writing something like `x=-5*sX:0.1:5*sX` for a step size of 0.1, or `x=linspace(-5*sX,5*sX,100)` for 100 linearly spaced points.

Comment: Yes,you are right!It was empty.I used 1000 points and now it's ok!Again,thank you very much..

Comment: @George: Re: learning Matlab, [this book](http://www.cambridge.org/us/knowledge/isbn/item1157524/?site_locale=en_US) might be of interest to you.